# Displaying the same image several times with multiple p:graphicImage without multiple HTTP requests

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I'm using `p:graphicImage` tag in my XHTML page to displaying the same image in small an large :

```
<f:facet name="header">#{msgs.ATTR_PICTURE}</f:facet>
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:graphicImage id="product_thumbnail" styleClass="thumbnail"
            cache="false" value="#{imageBean.streamedImageById}">
        <f:param name="productId" value="#{_product.id}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
    <p:tooltip id="imagebigger" for="product_thumbnail" position="right" showDelay="0" showEffect="blind" styleClass="tooltip_thumbnail">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.streamedImageById}" styleClass="thumbnail_large" cache="false">
            <f:param name="productId" value="#{_product.id}" />
        </p:graphicImage>
    </p:tooltip>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I would like to avoid the 2 HTML requests systematically for each image to display. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: I assume you tried changing the`cache="false"` to `cache="true"`? And it did not help?

Comment: hummm! cache=true is solving the 2 html requests but if for some reasons the image has been updated, the page will not refreshed with last modification when going back to it. Only if the page is refreshed (F5). I'm wondering if a duration can be set for the cache.

Comment: So how would you solve this contradiction in plain html/http? Right... cache timeouts like you suggested. So look for a new question about this new problem. I'll create an answer for this initial question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `stream` attribute and set it to `false`.
This will render the image in base64 instead of rendering the URL to the image.
I don't suggest it as the markup will be very big and probably much worse performance.

Comment: yes of course; Just without additional HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

I you remove the `cache="false"` from the first `p:graphicImage` (it defaults to `true`) the image is retrieved in the first `<img ... />` (which the `p:graphicImage` renders to) on the client and just displayed from the client cache for the second one without retrieving it twice.

The `cache="false"` might have been there for a reason like you mentioned in the comments, but that is effectively a new question for which there are several Q/A in Stackoverflow but which one is the most appropriate depends on the details of your use case. Your new question might either be a duplicate again or a new valid question on its own... It might even be that returning the `cache="true` on the first `p:graphicImage` and replacing the second one with something else (even some pure client-side 'duplication' e.g.) might be a good approach.

Comment: it solves the issue when clicking on the same page -> the number of requests is divided by 2. But when coming from another page, i can still see the same number of requests. Is it linked because my Bean is SessionScoped ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. if you have any reference about the last approach you mentionned i'm interested in.